# Rename 1 files multiple different names from a database

Tags: database, file, console-application, rename

So i know how to rename multiple files and even a single file. I know how to increment the names too. But what I am struggling with is renaming 1 single file, many different names from a db. An example is renaming `textFile.txt` to 100 different `strings` coming from a db `("file", "dog", "cat", "etc...")`. I'm needing help after I've set up a connection to the db, where do I go from there? I'm feeling like I need an `IEnumerable` of some sort, then like a `forearch` to iterate through. Just not sure how to write that. FYI I'm just using a ConsoleApp. Thanks!

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection Locations = new SqlConnection(ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.locationsDB);

            string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\1\Desktop\a";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\1\Desktop\b";

            CopyDirectory(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }

        public static void CopyDirectory(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                SqlConnection Locations = new SqlConnection(ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.locationsDB);

                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                foreach (string sourceFilePath in files)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
                    {
                        string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sourceFilePath);
                        string sourceFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
                        string targetFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, "10000" + i + fileExt);
                        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output would look like (

```
100001
100002
100003
100004
110001
110002
110003
110004
111001
111002
111003
111004
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the db connection and just use a .txt file, then set your `string[] = File.ReadAllLines(file)`. Then use a `foreach` loop instead of a for loop to iterate through each line.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\1152092\Desktop\a";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Users\1152092\Desktop\c";

            CopyDirectory(sourcePath, targetPath);
        }

        public static void CopyDirectory(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                foreach (string sourceFilePath in files)
                {
                    string[] entityNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1152092\Desktop\Locations.txt"); 

                    foreach ( string entity in entityNames)
                    {
                        string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sourceFilePath);
                        string sourceFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
                        string targetFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, entity + fileExt);
                        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```